# Index error after adding new lookup/type value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I get an index error on customertype.

I am new to EF so be patient with me.

I have a desktop application in .net core. With a form with fields from customers, one of those fields is a dropdownbox with customertype. So i have 2 models customer(with a field type of customertype) and customertype. in the dropdownbox i have added an extra value of 'add new type'. That opens a model dialog form to add new customer types.

So i select add new type field, the customer type dialog form is opened. I add a type, save it. Close the popup. Fill in the rest of the fields and click on save to save the customer. But then I get an index error on customertype.

How can I best solve this?
Can I somehow tell EF not to save CustomerType, when saving Customer?

@Jonathan:
What code you want? Also of my forms? I can post the things of EF but it is mostly the same as all the examples:

```
public class TestContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DBCustomer> Customers { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<DBCustomerType> CustomerTypes { get; set; } = null!;
   
    public TestContext()
    { 
    }

    public TestContext(DbContextOptions<TestContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DBCustomer>().HasOne<DBCustomerType>(b => b.Type).WithMany(t => t.Customers).HasForeignKey(b => b.TypeId);       
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        if (!options.IsConfigured)
        {
            options.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=c:\\...");
        } 
    }
}

public class CustomerTypeRepository : ICustomerTypeRepository
 {
     private readonly TestContext _context;
     private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
     private bool _changed = false;
     private List<CustomerType> _cashedTypes = new List<CustomerType>();
     
     public CustomerTypeRepository(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, TestContext context)
     {
         _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
         _context = context;
     }

     public bool AddCustomerType(CustomerType customerType)
     {
         if (DoesCustomerTypeAlreadyExist(customerType.TypeName)) return false;
         DBCustomerType customerTypeDB = customerType.ToDBCustomerType();
         
         _context.CustomerTypes.Add(customerTypeDB);
         _context.SaveChanges();
         _changed = true;
 
         customerType.Id = customerTypeDB.Id;
         return true;
     }
}

public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private readonly TestContext _context;
    private readonly ICustomerTypeRepository _customerTypeRepository;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public CustomerRepository(TestContext context, ICustomerTypeRepository customerTypeRepository, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _context = context;
        _customerTypeRepository = customerTypeRepository;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }


    public void AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        DBCustomer dbCustomer = Customer.ToDBCustomer();
        
        CustomerType? existingCustomerType = _customerTypeRepository.GetCustomerTypeByName(dbCustomer.Type.Type);

        if (existingCustomerType != null)
        {
            dbCustomer.Type = existingCustomerType.ToDBCustomerType();                
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();                
        }
       
        _context.Customers.Add(dbCustomer); //<- error on CustomerType Index
        _context.SaveChanges();
        Customer.Id = dbCustomer.Id;     
    }

public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
{
    return _context.Customers.Include(c => c.Type).ToList().ToCustomers();
}

}

public class DBCustomerType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; } = null!;

    public List<DBCustomer> Customers{ get; set; }

    public DBCustomerType()
    {
    }
}

public class DBCustomer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; } = null!;

    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public DBCustomerType Type { get; set; } = null!;

    public DBCustomer()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, including code.

Comment: What's your error message ? Could you share it ? And where do you get it ? "not to save CustomerType," Do you try `Customer.CustomerType=null;` ?

Comment: @QingGuo The error message is : System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'DBCustomerType' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'

Comment: @QingGuo  I get it when i try to save customer or rather add it to the context : _context.Customers.Add(dbCustomer);                                                                                I want to set the customertype.. The customertype is selected by the dropdownbox and is part of the customer (customertypeid needs to be set in the database). I know i get the error because i already saved a type in the dialog form. And because customertype is part of customer it wants to add the same thing again when saving customer.

Comment: Try to not add  dbCustomer.Type, just add `TypeId` .

Comment: @QingGuo This solved the problem, thanks. But i think it is weird that you have to remove the relationship. It would have been nicer if you could just turn tracking off for the relationship table....